# The relationship between namespace and actual files layer

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, hierarchy

OK, just as the title asked, I currently worked on a asp.net website, I found out that all the aspx and ascx files actually stay in one namespace, however there are different directory hierarchy between them.  See below example.

```
Mainsite
   |    Dialogs
   |       |   Help.ascx
   |       |   Price.aspx
   |    Includes
   |       |   QuickLink.acsx
   |    Members
   |    Orders
   |    Login.aspx
   |    Default.aspx
```

Like above example, all aspx ans ascx files belong to namespace **Order**, however Login.aspx and Price.aspx are in different directory. I mean by default when you create a aspx file in certain directory, the default namespace will inherit the directory information.

The thing is that I found at a frequently happened bug, is in Default.aspx there is ajax call to **Dialogs/Price.aspx**, then the error message can not find **Dialogs/Dialogs/Price.aspx**,  it is weird.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET web application project (File->New Project), or a Web Site (File->New Web Site)? The web sites do strange things with namespaces (which is one reason I don't use them).

Comment: Without seeing the AJAX call, this is going to be a hard one to troubleshoot.

Comment: Oh, it is a asp.net web application project